# Open browser in desktop mode

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to set in intent for opening a browser in desktop mode?

I create my intent the following way:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Are there parameters I can add to the intent or the url to open the url in desktop mode (assuming selected browser supports desktop mode)?

Comment: There are no standards for this.

Comment: Thanks, is there at-least a standard for the default browser?

Comment: None that are documented, and I haven't poked through the code to see if there's anything undocumented. I'll be a bit surprised if there is, though.